# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException when deleting record

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am coding an app for android. However, I have a problem with delete a record in sqlite. Can you help me to solve problem. When I click delete button, LogCat will appear a problem:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0
```

This is code:

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.Delete:
        int itemId = item.getItemId();
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo menuinfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

        dm.delete(menuinfo.id);
        list.remove(menuinfo.position);

        popupToast(" records deleted");
        displayListScreen();

        return true;

    default:
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}`
```

This is code of database:

```
public void delete(long id) {
    String where = "id = " + id;
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME, where, null);
}
```

Editted....

Sorry you guys, The first time i take part in. Now I will post it dor you guys.
LogCat

```
    10-28 17:51:03.586: D/libEGL(3831): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
10-28 17:51:03.586: D/libEGL(3831): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
10-28 17:51:03.586: D/libEGL(3831): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
10-28 17:51:03.596: I/Adreno200-EGL(3831): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:294>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB.04.01.01.00.036_msm8960_JB_CL2644550_release_AU (CL2644550)
10-28 17:51:03.596: I/Adreno200-EGL(3831): Build Date: 07/31/12 Tue
10-28 17:51:03.596: I/Adreno200-EGL(3831): Local Branch: 
10-28 17:51:03.596: I/Adreno200-EGL(3831): Remote Branch: quic/master
10-28 17:51:03.596: I/Adreno200-EGL(3831): Local Patches: NONE
10-28 17:51:03.596: I/Adreno200-EGL(3831): Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB.04.01.01.00.036 +  NOTHING
10-28 17:51:03.626: D/OpenGLRenderer(3831): Enabling debug mode 0
10-28 17:51:13.856: D/AndroidRuntime(3831): Shutting down VM
10-28 17:51:13.856: W/dalvikvm(3831): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415f2930)
10-28 17:51:13.896: E/AndroidRuntime(3831): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-28 17:51:13.896: E/AndroidRuntime(3831): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
10-28 17:51:13.896: E/AndroidRuntime(3831):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
10-28 17:51:13.896: E/AndroidRuntime(3831):     at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:399)
10-28 17:51:13.896: E/AndroidRuntime(3831):     at example.coursework.MainActivity.onContextItemSelected(MainActivity.java:135)
10-28 17:51:13.896: E/AndroidRuntime(3831):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2566)
10-28 17:51:13.896: E/AndroidRuntime(3831):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DialogMenuCallback.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:3899)
10-28 17:51:13.896: E/AndroidRuntime(3831):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
10-28 17:51:13.896: E/AndroidRuntime(3831):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
10-28 17:51:13.896: E/AndroidRuntime(3831):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
10-28 17:51:13.896: E/AndroidRuntime(3831):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuDialogHelper.onClick(MenuDialogHelper.java:167)
10-28 17:51:13.896: E/AndroidRuntime(3831):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:941)
10-28 17:51:13.896: E/AndroidRuntime(3831):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
10-28 17:51:13.896: E/AndroidRuntime(3831):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
10-28 17:51:13.896: E/AndroidRuntime(3831):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2749)
10-28 17:51:13.896: E/AndroidRuntime(3831):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3423)
10-28 17:51:13.896: E/AndroidRuntime(3831):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
10-28 17:51:13.896: E/AndroidRuntime(3831):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-28 17:51:13.896: E/AndroidRuntime(3831):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-28 17:51:13.896: E/AndroidRuntime(3831):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
10-28 17:51:13.896: E/AndroidRuntime(3831):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-28 17:51:13.896: E/AndroidRuntime(3831):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-28 17:51:13.896: E/AndroidRuntime(3831):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
10-28 17:51:13.896: E/AndroidRuntime(3831):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
10-28 17:51:13.896: E/AndroidRuntime(3831):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-28 17:51:15.158: I/Process(3831): Sending signal. PID: 3831 SIG: 9
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    TextView selection;
    public int idToModify;
    DataManipulator dm;
    List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    List<String[]> names2 = null;
    String[] stg1;

    // List view
    private ListView lv;

    // Listview Adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    // Search EditText
    EditText inputSearch;

    // ArrayList for Listview
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        View button1Click = findViewById(R.id.addButton);

        button1Click.setOnClickListener(this);

        dm = new DataManipulator(this);
        names2 = dm.selectAll();

        stg1 = new String[names2.size()];

        int x = 0;
        String stg;

        for (String[] name : names2) {
            stg = "Name: " + name[1] + "\n" + "Gender: " + name[2] + "\n"
                    + "Height: " + name[3] + "\n" + "Age: " + name[4] + "\n"
                    + "Hair Color: " + name[5] + "\n" + "Comment: " + name[6]
                    + "\n" + "Phone Number: " + name[7];

            stg1[x] = stg;
            x++;
        }

        // Listview Data

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view1);
        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
        registerForContextMenu(lv);

        // Adding items to listview
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item,
                R.id.product_name, stg1);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        /**
         * Enabling Search Filter
         * */
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                    int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
    }

    // Create Context Menu
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
        menu.setHeaderTitle(stg1[info.position]);
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    }

    // When User Selected Contexted Menu
    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.Delete:
            int itemId = item.getItemId();
            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo menuinfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

            dm.delete(menuinfo.id);
            list.remove(menuinfo.position);






            popupToast(" records deleted");
            displayListScreen();

            return true;

        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


    /*private void deleteRecords() {
        // Create and display the Alert dialog
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setMessage("Do you really want to delete selected records?")
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                })
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {

                                int position = 0;
                                String[] delete = names2.get(position);
                                String idString = delete[(position)];
                                long idLong = Long.valueOf(idString);
                                dm.delete(idLong);
                                popupToast(" records deleted");
                                displayListScreen();

                            }
                        }).show();

    }*/

    private void popupToast(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private void displayListScreen() {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.addButton:
            Intent i = new Intent(this, Coursework.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;

        }
    }

}
```

Sorry and Thank you so much

Comment: Which line did you get the exception for?

Comment: I editted already...Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question lacks details, but still, the only place in the code you posted you could get `IndexOutOfBoundsException` exception is this line:

```
list.remove(menuinfo.position);
```

Assuming `list` is an instance of [`java.util.List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html), you're getting this exception because either `menuinfo.position` is lower than zero or greater than the number of elements in `list`.

The immediate fix would be:

```
if (menuinfo.position < 0 || menuinfo.position >= list.size()) {
  // Warning, invalid position
} else {
  list.remove(menuinfo.position);
}
```